# what does 'presume away' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the movie, Tenet, when the protagonist goes to the restaurant to meet Mr. Crosby, the steward asks him "I presume you mean Sir Michael Crosby's lunch?"
Then the Protagonist says "presume away."
I can't understand what it means. Does it mean 'think as what you want'?

Comment: Yes, 'away' in this context is the sense "continuously or repeatedly, or in a busy way".

Comment: @Grace: your question needs more context. At the moment, you have one comment and one answer and either could be correct.

Answer (score 3):

This is distinctly idiomatic.

away = "continuously or repeatedly, or actively".

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/away)

This definition is relevant but in my experience there are significant other implications. The Protagonist is saying something on the lines of:

*"Presume as much as you like, as long as you like, until you don't want to do it any more, but all that matters to me is that you take me to Mr Crosby."* He may also also be implying that the tone of the steward (by using the word *presume* rather than asking the simpler "*Are you joining Mr Crosby at lunch, sir?*") is inappropriately lofty and patronizing.

Comment: Yeah, it should be noted that "Let's presume away the possibility that X is Y" has an entirely different meaning.

Comment: On a scale of decreasing idiomaticity, 'The clock was ticking away' / 'He was snoring away'  ... "May I smoke, Bertie?" _ "Oh, smoke away, old thing!" ['Jeeves and Wooster'; I've not checked for absolute accuracy) ...  "I presume you mean Sir Michael Crosby's lunch?" Then the Protagonist says "presume away."  OP's example is really pushing it, very tongue-in-cheek (and possibly rather rude). The Wodehouse example is (typically for Bertie) daft but well-disposed.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is clearly ironic, and the irony might be directed at the *pretentious style* in which the stewart addresses the protagonist. (But it may also be related to the character of the protagonist: one can like to be ironic when one is in a good mood, or one may like to manifest a "I don't care what you think" attitude). I do not know the movie, so sorry if I misunderstand your context.  But it seems to me that the protagonist picks up particularly on the verb ***presume***. ***Presume away*** in this situation is a very laconic way of saying:

> ***Go ahead*** / ***Suit yourself*** *and presume to your fill!* /***Be my guest!***

Answer (score 0):

I think he simply means "your presumption is correct and I do mean Sir Michael Crosby's lunch".

It seems to be a polite answer with the same tone as the questioner.